# c# custom group by really slow for large data set

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

When I run the following code where campaigns.Count() is 200,000 this code is really slow.

```
List<Campaign> listCampaigns = new List<Campaign>();
        foreach (var item in campaigns)
        {
            if (listCampaigns.Where(a => a.CampaignName == item.CampaignName && a.Term == item.Term).Count() == 0)
            {
                //this doesn't exist
                listCampaigns.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                //this exists already
                var campaign = listCampaigns.Where(a => a.CampaignName == item.CampaignName && a.Term == item.Term).First();
                campaign.TotalVisits += item.TotalVisits;
                List<Conversion> listConversions = item.Conversions.ToList();
                listConversions.AddRange(campaign.Conversions.ToList());
                campaign.Conversions = listConversions.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Is there anyway to optimize parts of this code or use another method to speed it up?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be significantly faster:

```
List<Campaign> listCampaigns = new List<Campaign>();
foreach (var g in campaigns.GroupBy(c => new { c.CampaignName, c.Term }))
{
    var campaign = g.First();
    campaign.TotalVisits = g.Sum(x => x.TotalVisits);
    campaign.Conversions = g.SelectMany(c => c.Conversions).ToArray();
    listCampaigns.Add(campaign);
}
```

Comment: This one should be used as an example for people who think that any `foreach`-based code is inherently faster than LINQ. Your solution is crazy fast compared to original code.

Answer (score 1):

Use .`Dictionary<Tuple<string,Term>,Campaign>`. You can put the CampaignName and Term into the tuple and use it to look up the existing Campaign in O(1). This makes the whole code O(n).

our current code is O(n^2) since it needs to walk the whole list to check for the presence of the current entry.

The code should look similar to this:

```
var dict=new Dictionary<Tuple<string,Term>,Campaign>();
var currentKey=new Tuple<string,Term>(item.CampaignName, item.Term == item.Term);
Campaign existingCampaign;
if (dict.TryGetValue(currentKey,out existingCampaign))
{
//already exists
}
else
{
//new
}
```

Comment: HashSet is no good, he needs the value, not only the fact that the values exists somewhere.

Comment: @rksprst You need to loop over all 200.000 items in any case. But with this code you don't need to loop over 200.000^2=40.000.000.000 items like in your original code.

Comment: But I recommend going with digEmAll's code. Both this and his code should be fast(no idea which one is faster), but his is more elegant. If you really need the performance you should code them both and benchmark. But I think both should be fast enough.

Comment: Looks like Tuple is only in c# 4.0. Can I just replace Tuple with a List, will that have the same performance? Both the keys are strings.

Comment: No it'd break the code, since I'm relying on the equality comparer of Tuple having value semantics whereas List has reference semantics. You could concat both strings with some delimiter to get a compound key. digEmAll's code on the other hand should work perfectly in C# 3, since anonymous types were already introduced then.

Answer (score 1):

Can you avoid slurping 200,000 campaign items' Conversions into concrete lists before adding them to a master list?

I would:

- Replace the Where().Count() with an Any() function, which will in the average case give the right answer faster.
- Refactor out the ToLists(); these functions take the source collection and clone it into a new collection instance, which is extremely time and memory-intensive especially in a loop like this. You're creating two Lists and an Array each iteration; stop that!

Here's the new code:

```
List<Campaign> listCampaigns = new List<Campaign>();
    foreach (var item in campaigns)
    {
        if (!listCampaigns.Any(a => a.CampaignName == item.CampaignName && a.Term == item.Term))
        {
            //this doesn't exist
            listCampaigns.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            //this exists already
            var campaign = listCampaigns.First(a => a.CampaignName == item.CampaignName && a.Term == item.Term);
            campaign.TotalVisits += item.TotalVisits;
            //Reduces the number of collection copies created per iteration from 3 to 1
            campaign.Conversions = campaignConversions.Concat(item.Conversions).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In that code:

```
    foreach (var item in campaigns)
    {
        var campaign = listCampaigns.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CampaignName == item.CampaignName && a.Term == item.Term);

        if (campaign == null)
        {
            //this doesn't exist
            listCampaigns.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            //this exists already
            campaign.TotalVisits += item.TotalVisits;
            List<Conversion> listConversions = item.Conversions.ToList();
            listConversions.AddRange(campaign.Conversions.ToList());
            campaign.Conversions = listConversions.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

You avoid going through the list multiple times using `FirstOrDefault`. Also, you most likely won't evaluate the list fully every time, saving additional time.

Comment: Still O(n^2) on 200.000 items.

Answer (score 0):

At least use `Any()` instead of `Count()` - you won't have to check the full list in that case:

```
if (listCampaigns.Where(a => a.CampaignName == item.CampaignName 
                        && a.Term == item.Term).Any())
```

Also as others have pointed out much faster would be a `Dictionary` for fast access, you would have to define a unique key value for each `Campaign` for that, then you could i.e. use a `Dictionary<string,Campaign>`

Comment: This can be further slimmed down to `if(!listCampaigns.Any(a => a.CampaignName == item.CampaignName && a.Term == item.Term)) ...`

Comment: This would still generate two evaluations of the list, while using `FirstOrDefault` and checking for `null` wouldn't evaluate it twice, and most probably not fully.

Comment: @Femaref - you are correct, I didn't even get to the part where he uses the 2nd linq query.

Comment: I guessed that. I just had that code structure memorized because it comes up alot in a project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dictionary<TKey,Campaign>`. That way you use hashtable for checking whether the values exists and find the corresponding value in O(1)

Code sample:

```
var dictCampaigns = new Dictionary<Key, Campaign>();
foreach (var item in campaigns)
{
    Campaign found;
    var key = new Key(item);
    if(!dictCampaigns.TryGetValue(key,out found))
    {
        dictCampaigns.Add(key, item);
    }
    else
    {
        found.TotalVisits += item.TotalVisits;
        found.Conversions = (item.Conversions.Concat(found.Conversions)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I used `Key` struct assuming you might not be able to use Tuples:

```
struct Key
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly int Term;

    public Key(Campaign camp)
    {
        Name = camp.CampaignName;
        Term = camp.Term;    
    }
}
```

I measured it roughly with `StopWatch` and it's like twice faster than your code but still can be optimized I think.

Comment: It's only twice as fast as his code? I would have expected it to be a hundred thousand times as fast.

Comment: @CodeInChaon: I was kinda puzzled too and then I realized that I was benchmarking on 50 elements, ouch. But there are much better solutions than mine in other answers, so no point in checking for 200000.